# How to transfer an array list of objects over the wire through GWTP action

Tags: gwt-platform

I am trying to create an action in which the server needs to response an array list of objects over the wire to the client through GWTP Action.

Category class

```
package com.business.share;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

public class Category implements Serializable{
    Long id;
    protected String name;
    protected String description;
    protected boolean status;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

GetCategories class

```
package com.business.client.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.shared.ActionImpl;
import com.business.client.action.GetCategoriesResult;
import com.business.share.Category;

public class GetCategories extends ActionImpl<GetCategoriesResult> {
    private ArrayList<Category> categories;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public GetCategories() {
        // For serialization only
    }

    public GetCategories(ArrayList<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public ArrayList<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }
}
```

GetCategoriesResult class

```
package com.business.client.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.shared.Result;
import com.business.share.Category;
public class GetCategoriesResult implements Result {
    private ArrayList<Category> categories;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private GetCategoriesResult() {
        // For serialization only
    }

    public GetCategoriesResult(ArrayList<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public ArrayList<Category> getCategories() {
    return categories;
    }
}
```

GetCategoriesActionHandler class

```
package com.business.server.handler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.actionhandler.ActionHandler;
import com.business.client.action.GetCategories;
import com.business.client.action.GetCategoriesResult;
import com.business.share.Category;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Query;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.ExecutionContext;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.shared.ActionException;

public class GetCategoriesActionHandler implements
    ActionHandler<GetCategories, GetCategoriesResult> {

    @Inject
    public GetCategoriesActionHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public GetCategoriesResult execute(GetCategories action,
        ExecutionContext context) throws ActionException {

        ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

        // dummy data    
        Category cat1 = new Category();
        cat1.setName("cat1");
        cat1.setDescription("cat1 desc");
        cat1.setStatus(true);   
        Category cat2 = new Category();
        cat1.setName("cat2");
        cat1.setDescription("cat2 desc");
        cat1.setStatus(false);  
        categories.add(cat1);
        categories.add(cat2);   
        return new GetCategoriesResult(categories);
    }

    @Override
    public void undo(GetCategories action, GetCategoriesResult result,
        ExecutionContext context) throws ActionException {
    }

    @Override
    public Class<GetCategories> getActionType() {
        return GetCategories.class;
    }
}
```

And this is a piece of code in CategoryPresenter, which sends async to server.

```
@Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();
    GetCategories getCategoriesAction = new GetCategories();
    dispatchAsync.execute(getCategoriesAction, getCategoriesCallback);
}

private final AsyncCallback<GetCategoriesResult> getCategoriesCallback = 
    new AsyncCallback<GetCategoriesResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(GetCategoriesResult result) {
        getView().getCategoryListBox().clear();
        ArrayList<Category> categories = result.getCategories();
        for(Category category : categories)  {
            getView().getCategoryListBox().addItem(category.getName());
        }
    }
};
```

I don't know what wrong with this piece of code, but GWT compiler always gives error like this.

> Compiling module com.business.Business
>     Validating newly compiled units
>        Ignored 3 units with compilation errors in first pass.
>   Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
>     Finding entry point classes
>        [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/.blah..blah..blah../businessapp/src/com/business/client/presenter/CategoryPresenter.java'
>        [ERROR] Line 75: No source code is available for type com.business.share.Category; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>        [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/.blah..blah..blah../businessapp/src/com/business/client/action/GetCategoriesResult.java'
>        [ERROR] Line 11: No source code is available for type com.business.share.Category; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>        [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.business.client.Business'
>        [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
>        [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly

Following this error message, it means, com.business.share.Category is not found, but this file is physically stored in that package already. I don't understand why GWT could not find it. I noticed anywhere that I make call Category class, it brings this error always.
Somebody's got an idea on what's going on?

[EDIT]
The problem is solved. 
In my Business.gwt.xml, I have

```
    <source path='shared'/>
```

But my share package is com.business.share (without d)
I just rename the package name from share to shared.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an empty constructor to the `Category` class.

Comment: Check the package name of `Category`. It should be `shared` not `share`